# How to do basic arithmetic operations for rows in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to figure out what I need to learn to do the following row operations. I've simplified everything in order to best convey exactly what I am trying to achieve.

My end goal is to for every row in my dataframe, subtract a value from a previous row in a different column.

Let's assume I have the following data frame:

```
    Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Difference
0   2014-07-14  197.61  197.86  197.44  197.60          
1   2014-07-15  197.72  198.10  196.36  197.23          
2   2014-07-16  198.11  198.26  197.42  197.96
```

I want to calculate the difference column, which is calculated as:

```
Open(n) - Close(n-1)  : where n is the current day.
```

So I am subtracting yesterdays closing price from today's opening price.

It should output to:

```
Difference
NaN
0.12
0.88
```

I am not sure exactly what kind of operations I should familiarise myself with to understand how to do this. I kind of got the hang of multiplying columns and doing basic operations with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to subtract a shifted version of `Close` from `Open`, you have [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) for that:

```
df.Open.sub(df.Close.shift()).rename('Difference')

0     NaN
1    0.12
2    0.88
Name: Difference, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using shift function.  Use a groupby if required:

```
import pandas as pd
Data = {'Date':  ['2014-07-14', '2014-07-15','2014-07-16'],
        'Open': [197.61, 197.72,198.11],
        'High': [197.86,198.10,198.26],
        'Low':[197.44,196.36 ,197.42],
        'Close': [197.60 ,197.23,197.96 ]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ['Date','Open','High','Low','Close'])
df['Difference']=df['Open']-df['Close'].shift(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

shift function does the job for you!
create 'diffs' array containing all the pairwise differences using `shift(1)`
and append to the `df` as a new column named 'difference'. the argument in the function indicates the step size you want to use for the pairwise subtraction.

`diffs = df['Open'] - df['Close'].shift(1)
 df['difference'] = diffs`